# How to add system permission file/system library to Android

Tags: android

I am attempting to follow Diane Hackborn's [request](http://groups.google.com/group/android-porting/browse_thread/thread/4559c6864fc5fb80?hl=en):

> *For a permission that allows an application to be root, it is okay to
>   add the permission to the framework
>   <...>. However, there still must be
>   some kind of shared library (even if
>   it is a stub) for the application to
>   request along with it, and the package
>   manager should not allow the
>   application get this permission unless
>   they also request the shared library.*

So I used the sdk's sample example of TicTacToe:

1. exported com.example.android.tictactoe.library to a /data/app/TTTLib.jar
2. added /system/etc/permissions/com.example.android.tictactoe.library.xml with lines:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <permissions>
       <library name="com.example.android.tictactoe.library"
               file="/data/app/TTTLib.jar" />
   </permissions>`
3. And compile com.example.android.tictactoe.MainActivity by adding a class folder pointing to the library but not adding the library itself to the .apk

It compiles, installs, starts running, but at the point when a library class were called crashes with error msg:

```
W/dalvikvm(  464): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime(  464): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  464): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.android.tictactoe.library.GameActivity
E/AndroidRuntime(  464):    at com.example.android.tictactoe.MainActivity.startGame(MainActivity.java:51)
E/A
```

What do I miss? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

In AndroidManifest.xml you have to enter the library dependency such as

```
<uses-library android:name="com.example.android.tictactoe.library"/>
```

Also i think you have to DEX the jar content before uploading it to the device, similar to the uploading of scala library to the device.
See http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~michelou/android/emulator-android-sdk.html and 
http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~michelou/android/android-examples-in-scala/android-sdk.zip
for scripts that dexes the jar into dexed jar :)
Hope it does make any sense.

Check bin/createdexlibs in android-sdk.zip

Basically it should be something like

```
~/android-sdks/platform-tools/dx --dex --output=TTTLib.jar TTLLib_input.jar
```